# Terminal Zoom in shortcut not working as written

Tags: command-line, 18.04

When using the default Terminal in 18.04, i'm getting weird behaviour.

- Zoom out shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> , ok that works.
- Normal Size shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>, that works.
- Zoom in shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>, doesn't work for me.yet, when i do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> it works. what gives?

Is this just me or is there something conflicting with this??

Comment: zoom in keyboard shortcut: `CTRL`+`+` is equal to `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`=`

Comment: My mistake was trying to use the + & - on my numeric keyboard which do nothing instead of the 'main' keyboard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the <kbd>shift</kbd> key because the primary key results in a `=` sign.

Just open any text editor and press the <kbd>=/+</kbd> key. If you press it with <kbd>shift</kbd> that results in a `+` sign, otherwise you'll get a `=`.

Get used to it because commands are often case sensitive! Take Vi editor, for instance, `a` is a different command than `A` (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)

Comment: In all the years ive used a computer,  I dont think i've realized this. 
The two keys next to 0 and backspace, look reversed.  
I always thouse minus was on top and underscore on the bottom, but I guess thats not the case clearly from typing them.   

however, if you open up chrome for example, and do Ctrl + =, it will zoom in like most applications do and yet it will show - and + to increase/decrease. 
Kinda bizare...